# Strange errors with delimiter when creating triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, delimiter

OK something weird is going on and I can't figure it out. I'm creating some triggers, but I get strange errors when trying to create them on the live DB. A sample query is this:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER debug_upd_before BEFORE UPDATE ON properties_availability
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO debug_upd_before SET timestamp = NOW(), avID = OLD.avID, avPropertyID = OLD.avPropertyID, 
    avAvailableFrom = OLD.avAvailableFrom, avAvailableTo = OLD.avAvailableTo, avPrice = OLD.avPrice, 
    avIsAvailable = OLD.avIsAvailable;
END|

...
```

which executes fine localy. I'm using phpmyadmin, cause I don't have any other access to the online DB. I know I don't have full permissions and think that it might have something to do with that, but the error I get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'delimiter |

not "you don't have permissions to do that" or something like that. The same happens when I try to execute something simpler like:

```
delimiter |
select 1|
select 2
```

The error I get is the same and I can't set a delimiter and the default doesn't work for me cause I have to use after the queries inside the triggers. I tried other symbols as delimiters, but the result is the same. Any ideas as to what the problem is and how to avoid it? Some of the triggers execute more than one query, if that makes a difference...

Thanks!

Comment: It could be a problem in phpmyadmin with delimiters.

Comment: I tried it with phpmyadmin locally and it works. I'm almost sure it's about permissions, but the error is about syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this statement (without delimiters) -

```
CREATE TRIGGER debug_upd_before BEFORE UPDATE ON properties_availability
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO debug_upd_before SET
  timestamp = now(),
  avID = OLD.avID,
  avPropertyID = OLD.avPropertyID,
  avAvailableFrom = OLD.avAvailableFrom,
  avAvailableTo = OLD.avAvailableTo,
  avPrice = OLD.avPrice,
  avIsAvailable = OLD.avIsAvailable;
```

Comment: Yep, that works, though I get the saner error: "Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation". Not sure if this syntax is gonna work for multiple queries, but I'm now sure it's a permissions issue and would need to fix that before anything else... Thanks :)

Comment: This syntax is only works for one query (when there is no BEGIN...END clause).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `|` is a bitwise or.
So you're using a reserved symbol as a delimiter.

Use `$$` instead.

Comment: As I said, I tried different delimiters, but that was not the issue. And | can be used as a delimiter - try the simple query I've given for example

Comment: Have you tried using `$$`? MySQL does say: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter |

Comment: Same thing.. There's something wrong with the error that is given when you don't have the privileges (it should not be a syntax error). I'm unable to set any delimiter, even though I can in other databases where I have more privileges. Not totally sure about that, but you should be able to use almost any string as a delimiter, regardless if it is an operator or not. I.e. `delimiter foo select 1foo select 2`, so the | is not the issue. I'm waiting for the admins of the server to change my privileges, there's nothing more I can do for now

Comment: @Nikoloff, thanks for taking the time to research that. You should really consider filing a bug report with MySQL: http://bugs.mysql.com/report.php